# Join two SQL Server Queries into one dataset

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a user that wants summed data on a report. I am able to get the correct data using two separate SQL Queries and they are as follows.

```
SELECT JH.ProjectID, SUM(EstProdHours) AS EstProdHrs, SUM(ActProdHours) 
AS ActProdHrs
FROM JobOper AS JO INNER JOIN JobHead AS JH ON JO.Company = JH.Company AND 
JO.JobNum = JH.JobNum WHERE JH.ProjectID <> ''
GROUP BY JH.ProjectID ORDER BY JH.ProjectID

SELECT JH.ProjectID, SUM(EstProdHours) + SUM(EstSetHours) AS Earned  
FROM JobOper AS JO INNER JOIN JobHead AS JH ON JO.Company = JH.Company AND 
JO.JobNum = JH.JobNum WHERE JH.ProjectID <> '' AND OpComplete = 1
GROUP BY JH.ProjectID ORDER BY JH.ProjectID
```

This two individual queries deliver the correct data on their own. My goal however, is to setup a SQL view with the results of these two queries together with result as shown below:

```
ProjectID   EstProdHrs  ActProdHrs   Earned
6000        480.00      1640.59      477
6001        621.00      2431.04      619
6002        6687.97     23234.23     6695.47
6003        414.97      4731.47      416.72
6004        208.00      2196.52      206.00
6005        2.00        76.77        NULL <--- This would show up if no completed ops in 2nd select statement
6006        20.83       819.29       18.83
```

I have tried to inner join the two queries and I can't seem to avoid "incorrect syntax errors". Here is that statement:

```
SELECT * FROM

(SELECT JH.ProjectID, SUM(EstProdHours) AS EstProdHrs, SUM(ActProdHours) AS 
ActProdHrs,'N/A' AS ValueMissingTableB 

FROM JobOper AS JO INNER JOIN JobHead AS JH ON JO.Company = JH.Company AND 
JO.JobNum = JH.JobNum WHERE JH.ProjectID <> ''

) AS 1

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT JH2.ProjectID, SUM(EstProdHours) + SUM(EstSetHours) AS Earned

FROM JobOper AS JO2 INNER JOIN JobHead AS JH2 ON JO2.Company = JH2.Company 
AND JO2.JobNum = JH2.JobNum WHERE JH2.ProjectID <> '' AND OpComplete = 1

) AS 2

ON 1.ProjectID = 2.ProjectID
```

I have also tried UNION and UNION ALL and it fails because the two queries don't have the same amount of records. I am hoping I am making a rookie mistake here and this can be done. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN instead

Comment: Thank you Serge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your tables to test this but cant you just do a left join;

```
SELECT A.ProjectID,A.EstProdHrs, A.ActProdHrs, E.Earned
FROM (

        SELECT JH.ProjectID, SUM(EstProdHours) AS EstProdHrs, SUM(ActProdHours) AS ActProdHrs
        FROM JobOper AS JO INNER JOIN JobHead AS JH ON JO.Company = JH.Company AND 
        JO.JobNum = JH.JobNum WHERE JH.ProjectID <> ''
        GROUP BY JH.ProjectID 
) A
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT JH.ProjectID, SUM(EstProdHours) + SUM(EstSetHours) AS Earned  
            FROM JobOper AS JO INNER JOIN JobHead AS JH ON JO.Company = JH.Company AND 
            JO.JobNum = JH.JobNum WHERE JH.ProjectID <> '' AND OpComplete = 1
            GROUP BY JH.ProjectID 
            ) E
        ON A.ProjectID=E.ProjectID
ORDER BY A.ProjectID
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you much. It didn't even occur to me to try the left join.

Comment: No problem - you said you are new working with SQL - it might be worth looking at the different join types, this page explains them clearly; https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
WITH A AS (SELECT JH.ProjectID, SUM(EstProdHours) AS EstProdHrs, SUM(ActProdHours) AS 
    ActProdHrs,'N/A' AS ValueMissingTableB 

    FROM JobOper AS JO INNER JOIN JobHead AS JH ON JO.Company = JH.Company AND 
    JO.JobNum = JH.JobNum WHERE JH.ProjectID <> ''
    GROUP BY JH.ProjectID ORDER BY JH.ProjectID
    ), 

     B AS 

    (SELECT JH2.ProjectID, SUM(EstProdHours) + SUM(EstSetHours) AS Earned

    FROM JobOper AS JO2 INNER JOIN JobHead AS JH2 ON JO2.Company = JH2.Company 
    AND JO2.JobNum = JH2.JobNum WHERE JH2.ProjectID <> '' AND OpComplete = 1
    GROUP BY JH2.ProjectID ORDER BY JH2.ProjectID
    ) 

    SELECT * FROM A
    JOIN B ON A.ProjectID = B.ProjectID
```

Comment: James' answer did the trick. I did try your solution and I got a error

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'JobHead.ProjectID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Sorry I edited my query to add a group by maybe that was a causing error  but if not  then ok